# PHP laravel - sitemap.xml

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, sitemap, xml-sitemap

I have a website built with PHP Laravel, in which the sitemap.xml shows an old version of the sitemap, not my recent update, in the browser.   I also viewed the sitemap file on the server containing the latest updates. the latest updates. Does anyone know why it is doing that?

Comment: Laravel doesn't create a sitemap for you, so you'll have to figure out how it was created and how to update it.

Comment: @aynber, it has a sitemap file in the server, and I updated it.  Why it is not showing the latest update?

Comment: If you updated the xml file, then it may just be cached, either by the server, or by Laravel itself.